# Is __all__ in __init__.py, needed when accessing class or method?

Tags: python

Googling around, I read many answers explaining that `__all__` is for 'from some.package.name `import *`' , restricting importable modules to only ones inside it.

I'm absolutely sure it's true, if I want to import all the modules using wildcard from packages. But my question is about when I want to import some lower level objects like class, functions than modules, from package directly, the `__all__` seems useless because to directly access the class from packages, it's the only way to import class from modules under the package into the `__init__` file.

Here's example
While doing some Django jobs, I recognized that Django-contributors really enjoy using `__all__`in the `__init__.py` files.

For example, in the basic Django package, models, `__init__` files go like this.

**`django.db.model.__init__.py`**

```
---skipped---

from django.db.models.base import DEFERRED, Model  #

---skipped---

__all__ = aggregates_all + constraints_all + fields_all + indexes_all
__all__ += [
    '---skipped---'
    'Prefetch', 'Q', 'QuerySet', 'prefetch_related_objects', 'DEFERRED', 'Model',
]
```

You can see that here, 'Model' is definitely included `__all__` ,but problem here is it's already imported upper lines, so if you don't include 'Model' in `__all__`, you can import it with from statement `from django.db.models import *`.

So I concluded that, in this case `__all__` is redundant or needless, and that the purpose of writing 'Model' despite its redundancy is that for readability.

Do you think it's the right conclusion?

Comment: Have you tested importing Model with `from django.db.models import *` without putting it inside of __all__? Also, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/6251569

Comment: Yep I tried that. I even set __all__ to None but it still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tutorial about modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) explains that `__all__` is actually used to restrict what is imported when you use `import *`.

If `__all__` is defined then when you import * from your package, only the names defined in `__all__` are imported in the current namespace.

So it can be redundant, but only if you put in `__all__` everything you import and define in your package.

Minimal working example:

`testing/__init__.py`:

```
from .moda import A
from .modb import B

__all__ = ['A']
```

`testing/moda.py`:

```
class A:
    pass
```

`testing/modb.py`:

```
class B:
    pass
```

Then when I `import * from testing`, I've got only `A` imported in current namespace, not `B`:

```
>>> from testing import *
>>> dir()
['A', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
>>> 'B' in dir()
False
>>> 'A' in dir()
True
```

Comment: Yep I tried that. I even set `__all__` to `None` but it still works..

Comment: Did you try with a simple minimal example?

Comment: I set `__all__` to None  in `django.db.models` , and then in the script using Model, I wrote the statement `from django.db.models import *` and called Model in that file. It still works

Comment: I meant a minimal ad-hoc example that you would have written, not based on django, because there could be other mechanisms in play

Comment: I edited the answer to include such an example. I admit I don't know what's going on with django but there may be other mechanisms we're not aware of. Nevertheless you've got the answer about the behavior of `__all__` in general.